# YARD equivalent for RDoc Sections :

Tags: ruby, rdoc, yard

There is an equivalent to RDoc sections, With YARD ?

See http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/rdoc/rdoc/RDoc/Context/Section.html

I want to build categorized API, and section could be the good way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, i just discover features i don't know before in Yard : the directives :

```
#@!<something>
```

Tokens prefixed by a "!", In this Directives
, there is :

```
#@!group <a group>
#@!endgroup
```

you could use it like :

```
# @!group Rendering methods                                                                                                                                                                        

def render
  [...]
end

def pretty_render
  [...]
end

# @!endgroup
```

And it's provide exactly what i want :)
Sorry, because it's in the main doc,

http://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md (see directives)